# ASP.NET MVC 4 sessions expiring after 10 min on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am currently building a website using ASP.net and MVC4. When debugging locally, sessions work as expected without any problems and expire 1 day after they have logged in. However on the live site sessions are expiring every 10 minutes and is becoming an annoyance.

Here is the web config

```
<sessionState timeout="1440" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
```

and

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1440"/>      
    </authentication>
```

Here is the login method from the controller.

```
public ActionResult LogIn(UserModel user)
    {
        var response = new RegistrationResponse();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var authUser = usersManager.IsValid(user);
            if (authUser != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                response.Authenticated = true;
                if (authUser.isAdmin)
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Admin"] = true;
                }

                var cart = (ShoppingCart)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"];

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] = new ShoppingCart(authUser.UserId, cart.Items);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = authUser.UserId;

                return Json("/Home");
            }
        }
        string errorMessage = "Your Email and/or Password could not be found.\n Please double check credentials and try again.";
        return Json("/Home/Login?errorMessage=" + errorMessage);
    }
```

I have checked the FTP to make sure that the web.config is up to date on the live site. However I am still getting knocked out every 10 minutes. Is there anything else that I can check, or could be the cause?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am using windows azure website and currently on the free trial subscription.

Comment: http://www.arunrana.net/2011/12/how-to-maintain-session-state-in-window.html

Comment: What makes you think the session is expiring?

Comment: Ah, thank you. To make sure I understand correctly. Azure is stateless and doesn't support local storage?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to mention how you deployed (VM, cloud service, websites) and, if websites, which tier?

Comment: DavidG, The user gets kicked off the site and is asked to log in again after 10 minutes. Which makes me believe the session is expiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be due to IIS app pool recycling. Which depends on app pool configuration (default values for standard IIS are 20 minutes for idle time-out and each 1740 minutes regardless the pool was idle or not), but windows azure websites are a different story:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/windows-azure-websites-%E2%80%93-a-new-hosting-model-for-windows-azure/

> The idle timeout period can fluctuate quite a bit. Currently the
>   timeout period starts at around 20 minutes, but then it can be as
>   short as 5 minutes. Now, you might be thinking, “Whoa! My site might
>   be taken down even after only 5 minutes of idle time?” Yes, that is a
>   pretty short amount of time; however, the reason the idle time
>   fluctuates is to deal with resource management that comes along with
>   being hosted in a shared system.

To avoid this behavior you can try to periodicaly ping your site or to use different session mode  like SQL Server Session or State Server mode. Or to not use the session at all and use some client side storage mechanism instead like cookies or local storage (I would prefer this option).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will look into other ways and appreciate the help since my approach doesn't look like it's possible.